# Insert error in sql cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL Server query with a cursor:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE(id varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @ids VALUES ('1098264', '1098859', '1098860', '1098267', '1098265')
```

But when I run the code, I get an error:

> Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Your table variable `@ids` has **one** column, but the `INSERT` statement inserts **five values** - not going to work, obviously....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one column in table i.e `id` and you are trying to insert 5 column values in table.

Try this

Create table :

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE(id varchar(50))
```

Insert values to table :

```
INSERT INTO @ids VALUES ('1098264')
INSERT INTO @ids VALUES ('1098859')
INSERT INTO @ids VALUES ('1098860')
INSERT INTO @ids VALUES ('1098267')
INSERT INTO @ids VALUES ('1098265')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a pair of bracket for each row like below:

```
INSERT INTO @ids VALUES ('1098264'),('1098859'),('1098860'),('1098267'),('1098265')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways of inserting multiple rows into a table (other than via a select statement)

```
INSERT INTO FOO (columna,columnb)
VALUES (1,a)
INSERT INTO FOO (columna,columnb)
VALUES (2,b)
INSERT INTO FOO (columna,columnb)
VALUES (3,c)
```

The second

```
INSERT INTO FOO (columna,columnb)
select 1,'a'
UNION ALL
select 2,'b'
UNION ALL
select 3,'c'
```

Thirdly (only works SQLServer 2008 and up)

```
INSERT INTO FOO (columna,columnb)
VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')
```

In the example in your question, you were trying to insert multiple fields into one column, which is why you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 1 column in the table but are trying to insert 5 values.
 First declare 5 different columns in the table to hold 5 values

For Example:-

```
        declare      @IDS_1 varchar(50)
                    ,@IDS_2 varchar(50)
                    ,@IDS_3 varchar(50)
                    ,@IDS_4 varchar(50)
                    ,@IDS_5 varchar(50)

        INSERT INTO @IDS VALUES ('1098264'
                                 ,'1098859'
                                 ,'1098860'
                                 ,'1098267'
                                 ,'1098265')
```